# Using the power series method, find the general solution of $y^{''} − x^2 y^{'}−3xy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, taylor-expansion

Converting the given into sigma notation:
$$\sum^\infty_{n=2}n(n-1)C_{n}x^{n-2}+\sum^\infty_{n=1}nC_nx^{n+1}-\sum^\infty_{n=0}3C_nx^{n+1}=0$$
Then reindexing and putting them all into a single power series:
$$2C_2+6C_3x-3C_0x+\sum^\infty_{n=2}\left[(k+2)(k+1)C_{k+2}+(k-1)C_{k-1}-3C_{k-1}\right]x^k=0$$
Then the resulting expressions follow:
$$2C_2+6C_3x-3C_0x=0$$
$$(k+2)(k+1)C_{k+2}+(k-1)C_{k-1}-3C_{k-1}=0$$
Am I right so far? Also should it be $-3C_0x$ or $3C_0x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $-3C_0$ is correct, as you split this term off of the third series, it is not a result of a compensation for added terms.

In comparing coefficients, you get separate equations for the constant and linear terms, thus
$$
2C_2=0,\\
6C_3-3C_0=0.
$$
This tells you that $C_2=C_5=C_8=...=0$ and that $C_0$ and $C_1$ are the free variables that determine all the other coefficients.

Comment: For $6C_3-3C_0=0$, I am meant to solve for $C_0$, correct?

Comment: I tried solving for $C_{k+2}$ and got $\frac{3-(k-1)}{(k+2)(k+1)}$, am I right?

Comment: @EricBrown : Do not forget the previous coefficient $C_{k-1}$. It should turn out that $C_6=0$, so that the the part proportional to $C_0$ has just the constant and cubic term.