# Recurrence formula for power series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, taylor-expansion

(I asked this question in an [earlier post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3641220/115115) and when I had follow up question they went unanswered so I'm posting it again.)

The given is:
$$y^{''}-x^2y^{'}-3xy=0$$

Converting the given into sigma notation:
$$\sum^\infty_{n=2}n(n-1)C_{n}x^{n-2}+\sum^\infty_{n=1}nC_nx^{n+1}-\sum^\infty_{n=0}3C_nx^{n+1}=0$$
Then reindexing and putting them all into a single power series:
$$2C_2+6C_3x-3C_0x+\sum^\infty_{n=2}\left[(k+2)(k+1)C_{k+2}+(k-1)C_{k-1}-3C_{k-1}\right]x^k=0$$
Then the resulting expressions follow:
$$2C_2+6C_3x-3C_0x=0$$
$$(k+2)(k+1)C_{k+2}+(k-1)C_{k-1}-3C_{k-1}=0$$

How I got  $C_{k+2}$ is:
$$(k+2)(k+1)C_{k+2}+(k-1)C_{k-1}=3C_{k-1}$$
$\bullet$Then dividing by $C_{k-1}$ on both sides
$$(k+2)(k+1)C_{k+2}+(k-1)=3$$
$$(k+2)(k+1)C_{k+2}=3-(k-1)$$
$\bullet$ Now dividing again to get $C_{K+2}$ alone

$$C_{k+2}=\frac{3-(k-1)}{(k+2)(k+1)}$$
which is my recurrence formula.

In my previous post, one answer said I could separate the first expression into $2C_2=0$ and $ 6C_3-3C_0=0$ which I haven't been taught so I am confused as to how thats possible, also which $C$-term am I meant to solve for, $C_3, C_2$ or $C_0$? And is my recurrence formula correct?

Comment: If $2C_2+(6C_3-3C_0)x=0$ for all $x$, then $2C_2=0$ and $6C_3-3C_0=0$

Comment: You forgot the C coefficients in the recurrence formula Eric

Comment: $(k+2)(k+1)C_{k+2}=-(k-4)C_{k-1}$

Comment: You have a sign mistake here. Normally it should be $$\sum^\infty_{n=2}n(n-1)C_{n}x^{n-2}\color{red} {-}\sum^\infty_{n=1}nC_nx^{n+1}-\sum^\infty_{n=0}3C_nx^{n+1}=0$$

Comment: @Aryadeva I edited the question to show how I arrived at my recurrence formula

Comment: @Aryadeva Wow can't believe I went this long without seeing that, thank you for pointing that out. Does that mistake mean that my reindexing is incorrect?

Comment: I posted an answer check the indices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum^\infty_{n=2}n(n-1)C_{n}x^{n-2}-\sum^\infty_{n=1}nC_nx^{n+1}-\sum^\infty_{n=0}3C_nx^{n+1}=0$$
Change indices:
$$\sum^\infty_{n=0}(n+2)(n+1)C_{n+2}x^{n}-\sum^\infty_{n=2}(n-1)C_{n-1}x^{n}-\sum^\infty_{n=1}3C_{n-1}x^{n}=0$$
Which gives us for $n \ge 2$:
$$$$
$$(n+2)(n+1)C_{n+2}=(n+2)C_{n-1}$$
$$\implies C_{n+2}=\dfrac {C_{n-1}}{n+1}$$
And
$$2C_2+3x(2C_3-C_0)=0$$
$$\implies C_2=0, 2C_3=C_0$$

You find the following recurrence formula:
$$C_{3n+1}=\dfrac {C_1}{n!3^n} \,\, n \in \mathbb{N}$$
Which gives the solution:
$$ y_1(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty {C_{3n+1}x^{3n+1}}$$
$$ \boxed {y_1(x)=x\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac {C_1x^{3n}}{n!3^n}=C_1xe^{x^3/3}}$$

---

For the second solution it's hard to find a recurrence formula and a pattern. Maybe you can leave the series that way and calculate some of its terms:
$$y_2(x)=C_0x^0+C_3x^3+C_6x^6+.....$$
Where $C_3=\frac {C_0}2$. Use the recurrence formula for the other coeffcients:
$C_{n+2}=\dfrac {C_{n-1}}{n+1}$
For example $C_6=\dfrac {C_3}{5}=\dfrac {C_0}{2*5}$

Comment: On the 3rd line, shouldn't it be $(n-4)C_{n-1}$?

Comment: It's $-n-2$ look at the signs @EricBrown

Comment: you have $-n+1-3$ @EricBrown

Comment: Where does the $C_{3n+1}$ come from?

Comment: calculate $c_4$ then $c_7$ then $c_{10}$ and so on...Then you guess that in fact these coeffcients are $C_{3n+1}$ @EricBrown

Comment: Use the following formula for calculating them $ C_{n+2}=\dfrac {C_{n-1}}{n+1}$ @EricBrown

Comment: Thank you for all your help so far, I do have one more question though. If I needed to find $y_1$ and $y_2$ how would I do so?

Comment: This equation is a bit complicated. The recurrence we had gives us another solution but thats not easy to express with elementary functions. You need the incomplte gamma function. So Thats why here I expressed only one solution. @EricBrown

Comment: I mean this recurrence relation $C_{n+2}=\dfrac {C_{n-1}}{n+1}$ gives more information on the second solution @EricBrown

Comment: @EricBrown you can calculate the coefficients $C_3,C_6,C_9$ and so on .for the second series solution.  I hope it's more clear ?

Comment: @EricBrown I added some lines I hope it"s more clear now Eric.

Comment: Yes that makes it very clear, but I'm stuck trying to write out the terms for $y_1$ since $C_2=0$

Comment: Dont start with $C_2$ @EricBrown these terms of the serie are all zero...we dont have power such as $x^2,x^5,x^8....$ all the coeffcients are zero. i am talking about these power of x such as $x^3,x^6,x^9,x^{12}.......$ These series constitute the second solution of the DE  Do you get the point Eric ?

Comment: I added some lines for the second series in my answer  did you read them @EricBrown  ?

Comment: Thank you for all your help and attentiveness, I have realized my error. I think I can finally understand this question start to finish. Thank you again @Aryadeva

Comment: You 're welcome @EricBrown